# For same size and weight, are alkaline batteries more amp hours than rechargeable?

Tags: batteries

For same size and weight, will alkaline batteries last longer or shorter than lithium ion recharageable batteries?

I am not just talking about new batteries here. When I use lithium rechargeables I notice that they seem to quickly degrade and last for a lot less time than they did when they were new, so I am asking about typical time, in other words, after the device has been used for at least 3 months and been recharged at least 20 times.

For example, let's say I have a walkie-talkie with a rechargeable lithium ion battery. I use it for 3 months and recharge it 20 times. Will the device last longer, as long, or less long, than if it had the same weight of alkaline disposable batteries?

Comment: What was your average discharge time/10h (%), Depth of Discharge <10% (really weak) How much above 4.1 was the Charge Voltage? 0.1V typ. But not ideal or more (bad) What part number is it? ( got link?) How many cells of each? Ideally it should last longer until 200 cycles or so unless you can answer above.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt That is my whole point. I don't want to worry about things things depth of discharge. The reality is that I typically use things till they run of juice. I know that is "bad" for the battery, but that is the practical reality. I want an answer that reflects real life, not some of kind idealized fantasy in which people never deplete their batteries before recharging.

Comment: If you are wise do not equate my reality to yours and think about my questions and answer if you can otherwise your experience is an isolated case

Comment: It’s like asking someone how often does the average person get tooth fillings or replacements when they don’t want to think about cleaning after a snack or meal., knowing that’s generally bad hygiene.

Answer (score 1):

For the same size and weight, Li-ion can hold ~20% more charge than an alkaline cell. [link](http://www.allaboutbatteries.com/Energy-tables.html).
Since Li-ion provide a higher voltage, 4.2V to 3.6V compared to 1.5V to 0.9V, the usable charge is also higher.

Comment: And that’s for 1 charge cycle

Comment: The question is about after the battery has been used for 3 months and charged 20 times. Assume that in many cases the battery was fully depleted before recharging.

Comment: It really depends on the battery, charger quality, discharge depth and lots of other parameters. A good quality cell, with proper charge/discharge protection can have 500 charge cycles with 90% charge level retention. An abused cell might last 3 charge cycles and be useless after that.

Comment: @TylerDurden: ROUGH estimate for fully depleted penalty is 1% per charge, so about the same.